# Databinding of Grid.Row value of embedded UserControl will not update GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a UserControl which embeds another view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="..."
             ...
             ...
             ... 
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Omega.GUI.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="700" d:DesignWidth="1000">

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="1" Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource GridSplitterWidth}"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1000*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <views:SingleWizardView Grid.Row="{Binding SingleWizardViewGridRowController}" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="2" Panel.ZIndex="150"  x:Name="SingleWizardViewDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
  </Grid>
```

As you can see I want to Bind the `Grid.Row` value to the `SingleWizardViewGridRowController`variable in the View Model. However this doesn't work at all. To test my data binding in general I made a dummy button with the same data binding, at the same position:

```
<Button Grid.Row="{Binding SingleWizardViewGridRowController}" Grid.Column="2" Panel.ZIndex="150" Content="dummy button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

...and this works great (I use a another button which changes the value of `SingleWizardViewGridRowController` for testing).

My question is: is a embedded view somehow limited when it comes to member values of the grid? Or did I miss something here?

Comment: Putting the embedded view into it's own grid and binding its `Grid.Row` value will also work:
    `<Grid Grid.Row="{Binding SingleWizardViewGridRowController}" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="2">
      <views:SingleWizardView Panel.ZIndex="150"  x:Name="SingleWizardViewDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Binding in SingleWizardView is looking at the DataContext of SingleWizardView and as SingleWizardViewGridRowController is not a property of SingleWizardView's DataContext the Binding doesn't work.

For the Binding to work you could try, for example, something like this:

```
<views:SingleWizardView Grid.Row="{Binding DataContext.SingleWizardViewGridRowController, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:SingleWizardViewManager}}" />
```

Comment: Hope I understood your question correctly:
Yes, both the SingleWizardViewManager (which is the xaml from my provided code) as well as the SingleWizardView (which is the embedded view) have separate viewmodels. Both are created from the code. There can be several SingleWizardView Instances in the SingleWizardViewManager-Window which the user can select from a listview embedded in a scrollviewer (which make them look like different tabs)

Comment: Ok, is the SingleWizardViewGridRowController property in the View Model of SingleWizardViewManager?

Comment: Exactly. My goal was to make a "Expand" Button to fill the complete SingleWizardManager Window with the current SingleWizardView, therefore changing the values for GridRow, GridColumn as well as the span values and bring them forward using ZIndex values. However, I was able to make it working as intended now by putting the SingleWizardView into its own Grid and Binding those values from that Grid (as explained in my comment above). I was just curious why it is working this way and not in the way shown in the question.